# Image is not updated on detail activity RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my App I developed a News feature with RecaylerView widget. Now I want to pass CoverImage and Date from this recyclerView to detail page of news. I can pass date of the news successfully. But the cover image is not shown in the detail page. I have found 0 image in my logcat in android monitor window. I cannot not identify what would be the problem here.

My Model class of news is-

```
public class NewsModel extends RealmObject {
     @PrimaryKey

    private int image;
    private String title;
    private String date;
    private String detail ;
    public NewsModel() {

    }

    public NewsModel(int image, String title, String date) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
    }
    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
  ......

 }
```

My adaper class for  news page is

```
  public class NewsAdapter extends 
   RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsHolder> {

    private List<NewsModel> newsObject;
    private Context context;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<NewsModel> newsObject) {
        this.context = context;
        this.newsObject=newsObject;
    }

    @Override
    public NewsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.news_row_layout,parent,false);
        return new NewsHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NewsAdapter.NewsHolder holder, int position) {
        final NewsModel newsModel=newsObject.get(position);

        holder.newsImage.setImageResource(newsModel.getImage());
        holder.newsHeadline.setText(newsModel.getTitle());
        holder.newsDate.setText(newsModel.getDate());
        holder.cardView.setTag(position);
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int pos = (int)view.getTag();
                openDetailNews(Integer.toString(newsModel.getImage()),newsModel.getDate());
            }
        });

    }

    //open Detail News Page
    private void openDetailNews(String...details) {
        Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailNews.class);
        i.putExtra("image",details[0]);
        i.putExtra("date",details[1]);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newsObject.size();
    }

    public class NewsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public CardView cardView;
        public ImageView newsImage;
        public TextView newsHeadline;
        public TextView newsDate;

        public NewsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            newsImage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_picture);
            newsHeadline=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_headline);
            newsDate=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_date);
            cardView=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_news);
        }
    }
}
```

The detail news page code where I want to get the cover image and date from news page is-

```
    public class DetailNews extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private List<NewsImageModel> newsObject;
    ImageView _coverImage;
    TextView _description;
    TextView _newsDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_detail);

        // Showing and Enabling clicks on the Home/Up button
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
        newsObject=getAllImageList();

        // setting up views and stuff
        setUpUIViews();

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //RECEIVE DATA
        Log.e("_coverImage",""+_coverImage);
        Integer coverImage=intent.getExtras().getInt("image");
        Log.e("coverImage",""+coverImage);
        String newsDate=intent.getExtras().getString("date");

        //BIND DATA
        _coverImage.setImageResource(coverImage);
        Log.e("coverImage",""+coverImage);
        _newsDate.setText(newsDate);

    }

    private void setUpUIViews() {
        _coverImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.news_cover);
        _description=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.news_description);
        _newsDate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.news_date);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.image_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(DetailNews.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new NewsDetailAdapter(this,newsObject );
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private List<NewsImageModel> getAllImageList() {
        List<NewsImageModel> images = new ArrayList<NewsImageModel>();

        ......

        return  images;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: your only image data is not coming or other data related like title detail also not coming ??

Comment: you have converted your image from int to string while sending then why are you trying to get int in your DetailNews class??

Comment: your image is integer datatype why? i think it needs to be blob type

Comment: @sumit yes,, because it was showing error in private void openDetailNews(String...details)  method. that is why I converted from int to string

Comment: @TapanKumarPatro Only Image data is not coming, date is loaded successfully

Comment: in this method getAllImageList() can you tell me how your are adding your data ?? from a webservice or static ? If you hava url for your image take image data type in your pojo class as string instead of int.

Comment: @TapanKumarPatro I have used this list to show other images in detail page. Exceprt cover image and description I have recyclerview to show list of images related to that news. Here I show those images in getAllImageList method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        int pos = (int)view.getTag();
        Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailNews.class);
        i.putExtra("image",newsModel.getImage());
        i.putExtra("date",newsModel.getDate());
        context.startActivity(i); 
        }
```

and then in your activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int imageId = intent.getIntExtra("image",0);
```

then use this resource id to set your image

```
_coverImage.setImageResource(imageId);
```

Comment: thanks it is working. Could you plaese explain this line int imageId = intent.getIntExtra("image",0); why do you set 0,

Comment: I am sending your resource id as integer value using int using the position you click and then receiving it in your NewsDetail class using this line :
int imageId = intent.getIntExtra("image",0); here the first thing is the key  which we used to send our value

Comment: Thank you. Also if you do not mind could you please explain what was the problem in this line //openDetailNews(Integer.toString(newsModel.getImage()),newsModel.getDate()); why I cant create a method openDetailNews(String...details) in this way

Comment: it is unnecessary to wrap an Integer value to string when we want the resource id as int

Comment: Yes I have upvotted it. Could you please also upvote my question

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

```
 String coverImage=intent.getExtras().getString("image");
 int convertCoverImage = Integer.valueOf("coverImage");
 _coverImage.setImageResource(convertCoverImage);
```

Comment: I am getting error for this code, it i sshowing null pointer exception

Comment: fix it:   
String coverImage=intent.getIntExtra("image","0");

Comment: One small correction in your code. int convertCoverImage = Integer.valueOf(coverImage); insted of "coverImage"

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly show a string url or any integer type into a imageview . You need to add Image lib's like Picaso or glide. 
follow below steps:

1.Add dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

2.In your adapter insted of your old code replace with

```
Picasso.with(context).load(newsModel.getImage()).into(holder.newsImage);
```

Your problem will be solved.

Comment: which code should I replace with that line. Sorrry I am ver ynew in Android developing

Comment: holder.newsImage.setImageResource(newsModel.getImage());

Comment: Tapan how will she get the position of recyclerview clicked using your code??

Answer (score 0):

```
private int image;
```

What integer data you are setting for the image? Is it a resource image?

Comment: If it is a resource image then you should pass it as integer only, do not convert it to string. openDetailNews(Integer.toString(newsModel.getImage()),newsModel.getDate());  , here is the problem.

Comment: openDetailNews(Integer.toString(newsModel.getImage()),newsModel.getDate());  , here is the problem.

Use **openDetailNews(newsModel.getImage(),newsModel.getDate());** 
and get the image resource as intent.getIntExtra("image",0);, where 0 can be any integer value(a default value), and then set the image resource with this resource id .